# Get a specific value from a PHP array

Tags: php, foreach

I am having the following json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "116376655202954/insights/page_impressions_organic/day", 
      "name": "page_impressions_organic", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 13059, 
          "end_time": "2013-02-22T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 15223, 
          "end_time": "2013-02-23T08:00:00+0000"
        },
```

And I using PHP to get the values of `value` and `end_time` the following foreach:

```
foreach ($page_impressions_organic['data'] as $page_impression_organic) {
    foreach($page_impression_organic['values'] as $key => $page_impression_organic_values) {
        $end_time = strval($page_impression_organic_values['end_time']);
        $ds = substr($end_time, 0, -14);
        $value = intval($page_impression_organic_values['value']);
        echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ']';
}}
```

Everything is working like it should, my issue is that now I have a different json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "116376655202954/insights/page_storytellers_by_story_type/day", 
      "name": "page_storytellers_by_story_type", 
      "period": "day", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 2043, 
            "page post": 293, 
            "user post": 5
          }, 
          "end_time": "2013-02-22T08:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": {
            "fan": 1085, 
            "page post": 398, 
            "user post": 5
          }, 
          "end_time": "2013-02-23T08:00:00+0000"
        },
```

and I am not able to get the same results because `value` is an array and I specially need only the `page post` values from it. I need to keep the form that my echo has for further scopes. I've made another foreach for like this:

```
foreach ($page_talking_abouts['data'] as $page_talking_about) {
    foreach($page_talking_about['values'] as $key => $page_talking_about_values) {
        foreach($page_talking_about_values['value'] as $page_talking_about_value) {
            $end_time = strval($page_talking_about_values['end_time']);
            $ds = substr($end_time, 0, -14);
            $value = intval($page_talking_about_value['page post']);
            echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ']';
}}}
```

but `$value` is 0 everytime... What I have to do?

Comment: Why not just decode your json string & work on it ?

Comment: `end_time` isn't within `value`. Get rid of the 3rd `foreach` loop.

Comment: PHP json_decode($jsonData, true); will return an multidimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its dead simple. See the rewritten code:

```
foreach ($page_talking_abouts['data'] as $page_talking_about) {
    foreach($page_talking_about['values'] as $key => $page_talking_about_values) {
        $end_time = strval($page_talking_about_values['end_time']);
        $ds = substr($end_time, 0, -14);
        $value = intval($page_talking_about_values['value']['page post']);
        echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ']';
    }
}
```

Your really do not have to iterate through the inner values array if you only need a known index. What happened in your solution is, that for each **value** in the nested value array you tried to get the index `page post`, but as the values of the nested array are not arrays the index `page post` returned a `null` which translatesd to `0` if fed into `intval`.

Beside that I really suggest to rename your variables to something more readable. Those long names with subtle differences make it difficult to read the code.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. The variables names are for testing purposes for now, I will use Ajax to make a GET request to a php file anytime this kind of operation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the third for-loop because the `value` array only exists once per `end-time`.

Try to change your code like this:

```
foreach ($page_talking_abouts['data'] as $page_talking_about) {
    foreach($page_talking_about['values'] as $key => $page_talking_about_values) {

        // note: removed third for-loop

        $end_time = strval($page_talking_about_values['end_time']);
        $ds = substr($end_time, 0, -14);

        // note: changed this line to directly read out the page posts
        $value = intval($page_talking_about_values['value']['page post']);

        echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ']';
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shud not directly loop through it. Decode the string  using json_decode and then do foreach loop and then again json_encode it